# ajax error in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created the page in wordpress admin. I'm using the ajax into it but it is not working it always run the error part and show message that is in error function. file url in ajax is in template ,I have tried all the path but it is not showing success message. Please let me know how can assign the file path or get the reason why this is showing the error alert?

i'm usig the following code

```
 var jqxhr =
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/data.php",
    data: {
        name : "The name",
        desc : "The description"
    }
})
.success (function(response) { alert("Success: " + response) ; })
.error   (function()     { alert("Error")   ; })
.complete(function()     { alert("complete"); })
;
```

Comment: I addition to the question being unintelligible, the problem is something you caused, so we would need way more information (WordPress doesn't do any AJAX without you adding something to do so).

Comment: I have created the admin section.the file path that i'm  using in ajax is working when I run it directly, when I use in  inside the ajax it is not showing success message.

Comment: You'll have to provide _some_ information.  Specifically, the error that's happening and the code that's causing the error.  For any request/response from the server (such as an AJAX call) you will also want to provide information about the runtime request being submitted and the response being received.

Comment: please I'm the code in question it is showing error inside the alert

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response you get from .success or .complete you can do something like

```
if (response == "error") { alert ("Error"); }
```

Your Ajax is successfully sending the information over so it will not error.

Your backend PHP has to throw an error back if there is a condition that does not meet

```
if (some condition) { 
    //do something 
} else echo "error";
```